# iOS top banner notification content customization

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

concerning iOS5 LocalNotifications:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NSZN.png): [image: screen shot]

- What is the maximim **visible** length of the message shown in the banner ?
- Is it possible to make the text size smaller so I can fit longer text ?
- Is it possible to change the title of the banner (instead of the application name by default), so I can fit even more text ?.

Thank you

Comment: Before trying to get too much text into the banner, remember that the notification will only be shown for a couple of seconds.

Comment: Yes I know, It would be enough for the user to get the information he's looking for ..

Answer (score 2):

The length of the string that you assign to the local notification can be any length. The cutoff for what the banner actually shows depends on the string (if it has capitals or other special characters). Based on testing it looks like you can fit about 40 lowercase characters in the banner before it truncates.

It is not possible to change the text properties of the Local Notification, including the title of the banner. The title will always be the app name.